# Dharmo Rakshati rakshitaha? How does it protect?

Tags: dharma

I see so many armymen/policemen protecting righteousness dying in the duty so how exactly dharma protects it? If dharma really protected the righteous then wouldn't they would do their duty for their country without fear?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29112/4732

Comment: But I have seen in news killing of lawyers fighting for the right cause , why didn't dharma protect them?@Rickross

Comment: It's a complex thing how karma functions .. but eventually dharma protects those who have protected it either in this life or in the next. In this way we have to understand it @Shiv

Comment: Everything is fine but when you talk about next life I start to get confuse , do you have any proof by logic about existence of next life? Then why would someone protect dharma?

Comment: Its upto to us what to follow .. the results will be obtained accordingly. Whether we follow scriptures is up to us .. there is no compulsion as such.. .. finding rational verification for every spiritual matters is impossible.

Comment: Mr. Ross is right. See, logic is this, if you protect dharma, dharma protects you. The lawyer who died fighting for a correct cause would get justice in a court of law, dharma will make sure his killers are punished. If killers go Scott free, probably that lawyer was adharmik in the first place but was fighting for dharma only in this instance. Further, his death is due to karma and not dharma adharma of this birth. Had he not some bad karmas, besides justice, dharma would’ve made sure that he doesn’t die. Look at the reverse situation. When you violate dharma, dharma will do the same to you

Comment: A live most recent example is Shri Kashi Vishwanatha temple. The lawyer opposing the Mandir died mysteriously one day, owing to some illness. Dharma violated the lawyer who Violated it. Mind you, he was a Hindu himself

Comment: You ask what proof you have that next life exists. I ask, what proof do you have that next life doesn’t exist?

Comment: Look at the condition of people's lives in Afghanistan and Pakistan. Once Afghanistan was the centre of higher education. Now people are there mostly illiterate and they are running behind a truck for bread.  Do you see how Dharma protected us?

Comment: Is it because of religion@AmritenduMukhopadhyay? But not all Indian states are well developed, i am pretty sure it would be the case of some Indian villages too?